# TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqiwi

Есть фрагмент когда который вызывает эту ошибку.

Python 3.6.5
Сам код:

```
import pyqiwi
paylink = pyqiwi.generate_form_link(pid=99, account=79094167269, amount=50, comment="hi")
```

Лог консоли:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\\Python\\lib\\urllib\\parse.py", line 856, in urlencode
      raise TypeError
      TypeError
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\\Users\\Fin\\Desktop\\PyProject\\Web\\cgi-bin\\processing.py", line 49, in <module>
            paylink = pyqiwi.generate_form_link(pid=99, account=79094167269, amount=50, comment="hi")
        File "E:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\pyqiwi\\__init__.py", line 470, in generate_form_link
            params[\'comment\'] = urlencode(comment)
        File "E:\\Python\\lib\\urllib\\parse.py", line 864, in urlencode
            "or mapping object").with_traceback(tb)
        File "E:\\Python\\lib\\urllib\\parse.py", line 856, in urlencode
            raise TypeError
            TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это похоже [на баг](https://github.com/mostm/pyqiwi/issues/15) в **pyqiwi**.

Но сама ошибка, идет дальше и связана с функцией `urlencode` из модуля `urllib.parse`.

Если просмотреть трассу, то можно увидеть что [проблема возникла в строке](https://github.com/mostm/pyqiwi/blob/master/pyqiwi/__init__.py#L473) `params['comment'] = urlencode(comment)`

Чтобы ее повторить достаточно вызвать код:

```
comment = "hi"

from urllib.parse import urlencode
urlencode(comment)
```

Однако это не единственная проблема, что я нашел в том коде – `PreparedRequest().prepare_url(url, params).url` вызовет ошибку, потому что `prepare_url` подготавливает `url`, но не возвращает его. Поле `url` после вызова `prepare_url` нужно запросить у объекта `PreparedRequest()`, поэтому я решил, что проще переписать код, пока автор его не исправит.

И, по-моему, он работает.

Код:

```
from requests.models import PreparedRequest


def generate_form_link(pid, account, amount, comment):
    url = "https://qiwi.com/payment/form/{0}".format(pid)
    params = {"currency": 643}
    if type(amount) == float:
        params['amountInteger'] = str(amount).split('.')[0]
        params['amountFraction'] = str(amount).split('.')[1]
    else:
        params['amountInteger'] = amount

    if comment:
        params['comment'] = comment

    if account:
        params['account'] = account

    preparedRq = PreparedRequest()
    preparedRq.prepare_url(url, params)

    return preparedRq.url


paylink = generate_form_link(pid=99, account=79094167269, amount=50, comment="hi")
print(paylink)

paylink = generate_form_link(pid=99, account=79094167269, amount=50, comment="Привет!")
print(paylink)
```

Консоль:

```
https://qiwi.com/payment/form/99?currency=643&amountInteger=50&comment=hi&account=79094167269
https://qiwi.com/payment/form/99?currency=643&amountInteger=50&comment=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%21&account=79094167269
```